# Error in Compiling C++. It's showing fatal error: Directory not found. Also .exe is not getting formed for the cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

[On pressing the run button it is showing me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv9W4.png)
As a beginner, I have no idea what should I do next.

Comment: Please don't attach images of error. Copy and paste the error message in the description of the question.

Comment: It means that VSCode cannot find the compiler you have told it to use.

Comment: As you can see it is trying to use the g++.exe compiler located at C:\msys64\mingw64\bin. Do you have this file? The error message is saying that you don't.

Comment: VSCode is too difficult for beginners. My advice would be to pick a simpler compiler. Since you are working on Windows I would recommend Visual Studio.

Comment: *As a beginner, I have no idea what should I do next* It would help you to get some help if you gave some indication of what you have done so far. It is not easy to setup VSCode correctly, so to get some idea of where you have gone wrong it helps to know what you have done so far.

Comment: You may want to try the same command that is run on the terminal in a cmd.exe. Also you may want to check if you MinGW bin folder is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: re-install the MinGW tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your MinGW-w64 setup seems to be broken.

You can test this without touching your MSYS2 folder by extracting a standalone MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ to a different location and point your VSCode to that.

If that still doesn't work, check your system's PATH environment variable. It may be pointing to a different location picking up dependencies (DLLs) for GCC in the wrong place.